# URI Spring Encoding Issue

Tags: spring-boot

I have a query param that contains "+" sign, I encoded it and pass it to a Spring Controller but the controller interprets it as space thus failing the API.
Sample

Name = test+fetch
URI passed from browser: abc.org/fetch?name=test%2Bfetch

How Controller receives it
name = test fetch

there is nothing with test fetch and thus the API fails

Is there a way we can solve this issue, decoding the param after spring resolves it doesn't solve the issue

Edit:
Updated Controller Code

```
    @GetMapping("fetch")
   public String fetch(@RequestParam("name") String name){
   return something;
   }
```

Comment: Show controller code.

Comment: If you want to override the request paramters, yon can try request filter classes.

Comment: I don't want to override the request param, my expectation is that I would either get a name as "test+fetch" or "test$2Bfetch"( so that i can decode)
Currently, I am getting the request param as "test fetch"

Answer (score 0):

I created an application using https://start.spring.io/ and your controller, and the encoding works as it's supposed to.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/z9rbe2gtpvzebqv/url-encoding.zip?dl=1

I think there's something before your application, may be a proxy, web server or Spring Gateway, that's decoding the parameter. Otherwise, download the app I created and prove that the problem exists.